# Expect to return a excel file but response not properly encoded to return a excel file

Tags: excel, rest, get, apache-poi

I'm sending an HTTP GET request expecting an Excel workbook as the response.However, the response is not properly formatted.I'm expecting download prompt as the response

```
@GET
@Path("bulkimporttemplate")
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Response getClientTemplate() throws IOException {
    final XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    WorkbookPopulatorFactory.createWorkbookPopulator("Client", "ClientTemplate");
    StreamingOutput streamOutput = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            wb.write(out);
        }
    };
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(streamOutput, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=clientTemplate.xls");
    return response.build();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that "response is not properly formatted"? You cannot open an `*.xlsx` file as a plain text file and expect a correct display. A `*.xlsx` file is ZIP file containing XML files and other files in different directories within that ZIP file. Open it using a unzip tool or using Excel and it should work. Btw.: `filename=clientTemplate.xls` should be `filename=clientTemplate.xlsx`. `XSSFWorkbook` produces a `xlsx` workbook and not a `xls` one.

Comment: @AxelRichter how can I get a download prompt as the response?